# how to create box shadow with requirements of angle and opacity

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shadow

How can you define the angle of shadow

i have to write css for modal shadow, with following requirements
opacity 50%, angle 120 degrees, distance 2px, spread 10%, size 6px and color #3a3a3a?

Comment: I always just use [this](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) but you'll have to translate your 120deg to positive or negative on the x/y axis relative to horizontal/vertical length to get it to show how you want.

Answer (score 1):

box-shadow: 1px 2px 5.4px 0.6px rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.5);

you can find many site in google which convert Photoshop Drop-shadow to ( box-shadow or text-shadow)

one of the popular site with this features is. 
http://www.melanieceraso.com/psd-to-css3/